# Angular ng-repeat best practice to only watch for updates inside the specific iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to render a table in which the user is allowed to edit some fields for each row, fields that will affect other fields in the same row.

For this reason I could not use bind-once on all the data I'm rendering.

If I got it right, simply using a code like the following

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in alist">
      <td>{{::a.id}}</td>
      <td>{{::a.cod}}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          ng-model="a.sel"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-sm"></input>
      </td>
      <td ng-if="a.sel">
        {{::a.desc}}
      </td>
      <td ng-if="!a.sel">
        "Other Content"
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

will cause that for each time a user checks or uncheks the *a.sel* checkbox, all the angular {{vars}} in the page (not the {{::vars}}) will be watched for changes.

If this is true (and therefore that's the reason why page is slow when hundreds of rows are loaded) how could I tell angular I only want it to check if something has changed inside that specific row, that specific ng-repeat iteration?

Not sure how to proceed to get good performances, any other tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **track by** to tell angular what it should be evaluating on:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="a in alist track by $index">
```

or

```
  <tr ng-repeat="a in alist track by a.id">
```

more on that in the **ng-repeat** [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: thank you @toskv, I did add _track by a.id_ but I don't seem to get such good performances on big tables. I guess I should probably leave ng-repeat and use something different, or maybe just understand how to unbind all the watchers that are not on the part of page the user can see. Still hope there is a simpler solution..

Comment: what I did when having large lists was to introduce windowing. Basically show only what the user needs to see and empty divs otherwise (or better 1 large empty div). That way  you can keep the number of watches angular has on the list to a manageable number.